# Django-import-export export also related field of a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

In my project I have a model like this:
models.py

```
class e_cart(models.Model):
    e_uid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    e_prodid = models.ForeignKey(p_prodotti, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product")
    e_qta = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Quantita")
    e_datain = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Insert Data")
    ....
```

I use django-import-export for export my data in admin panel and in `admin.py` I do:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class OrderAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ('onum',)
    list_display = ('onum', 'date', 'paid', 'onotes', 'totord', 'obank')
    ordering = ('-date', 'onum')
```

Now for example the e_uid field is exported as just an id (1,2 ecc) but I would export the select_related() fields for example e_uid.firstname, e_uid.lastname ecc

How can I modify my code for export also related field of my model?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

When you declare your resource, it is possible to follow Model relationships ([docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options))

Declare a resource (with fields) (taken from the [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app)):

```py
class BookResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('author__name',)
```

Reference the resource in your Admin class:

```py
class BookAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'author', 'added')
    list_filter = ['categories', 'author']
    resource_class = BookResource
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide in **django-import-export** docs

[Avanced Data Manipulation on Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export)

It will walk you through exporting related fields of any model.

Comment: Tanks a lot, i use django-import-export directly in admin interface, i don't understand how could export related fields i my case. Thanks